# Android kotlin bottomSheetBehavior COLLAPSED after clik button

Tags: android

Hi i want tu COLLAPSED my bottomSheetBehavior after click button  I do this :

```
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
```

But it doesn't work , what I do wrong

this is my bottomSheetBehavior :

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {

        Log.e("a","a")
    }
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

        val upperState = 0.66
        val lowerState = 0.33
        if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING ) {
            if(slideOffset >= upperState){
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
            if(slideOffset > lowerState && slideOffset < upperState){
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
            }
            if(slideOffset <= lowerState){
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
            }
        }
           changeSize()
    }

})




 private fun changeSizer() {
        val screenHeight = getScreenHeight(this)
        bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = (screenHeight * 0.2).toInt()

        val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = llBottomSheet.layoutParams
        params.height = (screenHeight * 0.8).toInt()
        llBottomSheet.layoutParams = params
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Set `fitToContents`

```
bottomSheetBehavior.isFitToContents = false
```

> Sets whether the height of the expanded sheet is determined by the height of its contents, or
>   if it is expanded in two stages (half the height of the parent container, full height of parent
>   container).

Default value is `true`. We have to set it to `false` to have option set height "manually".

## Set `peekHeight`

Sets the height of the bottom sheet when it is collapsed.
Second parameter (`true`) is responsible for animating between the
old height and the new height.

```
bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight, true)
```

## Full working example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<LinearLayout>

    private val bottomSheetHeight: Int by lazy {
        bottom_sheet.height
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet)
        bottomSheetBehavior.isFitToContents = false

        setInitValue()

    }

    /**
     * Use listener, because at the beginning The UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet.
     */
    private fun setInitValue() {
        bottom_sheet.run {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
                ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (bottom_sheet.isShown) {
                        // Show only 25%
                        updatePeekHeight(0.25f)
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val factor: Float = when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.option_full -> 1f
            R.id.option_3_4 -> 0.75f
            R.id.option_2_4 -> 0.50f
            R.id.option_1_4 -> 0.25f
            R.id.option_hide -> 0f
            else -> 1f
        }

        updatePeekHeight(factor)

        return true
    }

    private fun updatePeekHeight(factor: Float) {
        val peekHeight: Int = (bottomSheetHeight * factor).toInt()
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(peekHeight, true)
    }
}
```

## Demo

[image]

Comment: But I want to only calopse not dissmiss